# Consuming PagedResources in abstract class

Tags: java, json, generics, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have a server that exposes data with the spring-data-rest project and now I am writing services to consume those data and I started with a generic service that will suit all the common needs, one of which is getting the Page object.

I configured my RestTemplate to use the Jackson2HalModule as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23239052/why-does-resttemplate-not-bind-response-representation-to-pagedresources).

I've tried a lot of combinations and I was only able to use consume it properly in a non-generic way like this:

```
PagedResources<Resource<Company>> response2 = restTemplate.exchange(getUrl(), HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<Resource<Company>>>(){}).getBody();
```

But trying the same code with T didn't work (Resource links were deserialized but content of Resource object was null)

```
PagedResources<Resource<T>> response3 = restTemplate.exchange(getUrl(), HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<Resource<T>>>(){}).getBody();
```

Generically I am only able to deserialize the Company data using the following code:

```
PagedResources<T> response1 = restTemplate.exchange(getUrl(), HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, PagedResources.class).getBody();
```

But this one doesn't deserialize the Resource object so the Company&Links data of what should be the Resource object are stored in a LinkedHashMap instead.

I also tried using the object mapper on the LinkedHashMap with data but I was unsuccessful. It's been a long day so I might be too close to see the correct way of doing this. I'll appreciate any help with this. Thank you.

The question: Is there a way of getting proper generics working in this case?

Comment: No. This doesn't work because of type erasure. You have to inject a non-generic instance of `ParameterizedTypeReference` (by which I mean without referencing any type variables). I answered [a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36840980/3788176) yesterday.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you for your answer, actually I already thought about supplying the non-generic instance from concrete implementation when I made it work, but thought that I'll find a way around it. So it's good to know that there isn't one :) I read about type erasure and understand the concept and the simple examples, but I am not 100% sure what type erasure actually does in this case. Would you be able to describe what is happening under the hood here? I would like to fully understand it .

Comment: Erasure simply means that it replaces `T` with `Object` when compiling (or `Bound` in the case of `T extends Bound`). Try doing this explicitly, and compare the results (should be the same).